# Lightroom: Photoshop documents not displaying in catalogue

Tags: lightroom, photoshop

When I edit an image in Photoshop, the image doesn't appear in Lightroom. Instead, I'm taken to a blank grey background where the image would normally be. If I return to grid view in the Library module, the .psd is not visible. Filtering by metadata shows that there are no files of type .psd in the current folder.

If I try to synchronise the folder, the .psd file doesn't appear; if I uncheck 'do not import suspected duplicates', I can see the .psd greyed-out, and the hover text informs me that it's already in the catalogue.

Any ideas what might be causing this bizarre error, and what I could do to fix it? It started without precedent a few days ago. I've tried restarting both Lightroom and Photoshop, my computer, and reinstalled Lightroom.

I'm using Lightroom 4.4 and Photoshop CS6 on Windows 7.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

EDIT: I've found the 'missing' edited files…they are indeed imported into the catalogue, but in a new folder in the catalogue's root with the same name as the sub-folder they actually appear in on my filesystem. Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The folders panel represents the actual file structure in Lightroom. Photos will not appear from subfolders unless you turn on the "Show Photos in Subfolders" option. This option is located under the "+" in the upper right corner of the folders panel.
When this option is toggled off, you must select each folder to see the images in that location.
This tutorial may help: http://tv.adobe.com/watch/the-complete-picture-with-julieanne-kost/quicktip-showing-photos-in-subfolders/

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but if you go into your Photoshop preferences, under File Handling, is "Maximize PSD and PSB file compatibility" set to "Never"? You need to save PSD with compatibility mode enabled to load them in Lightroom. ([Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/lightroom/using/WS42D207D7-B290-4baa-A896-AB71965BF24B.html).)

As for not even seeing the gray tile after editing it in the grid view, it may be stacked under the original. If you see a little white box with a "2" in it over the original photo, click the "2" to expand the stack.

By the way, if you're just creating layered compositions — alpha blends, layer masks, etc. — you can use TIFF instead of PSD, which is much less problematic with Lightroom. (DNG is actually a variant of TIFF, and of course you know that Lightroom loves DNG.) You really only need to use PSD when saving something with layer styles, smart objects, adjustment layers, and other Photoshop specific features.

Comment: Good suggestion, but sadly it doesn't work! I had already set maximise compatibility to on, and the same issue occurs when I use TIFFs rather than PSD.

Comment: Before I read your edit, I was thinking that the PSDs might have been in LAB or CMYK. So now I'm guessing that you accidentally changed some import option- but you've probably thought of that already.